Feedback for 1/0-1/0-1/0-2
I’m running 100’ line from main panel to subpanel. I was told 1/0-1/0-1/0-2 aluminum wire will work and 1-1/4” conduit will work. Two 90 elbows and a 45 elbow. Any issues? Will ser type of wire work?

Welcome. Please take the [tour]. Also, on any site like this, please search before posting. These are very common questions, and you should only be asking one question in a post.

That's fine. 1/0 cable will allow 120 amps on that circuit per NEC 110.14(C) and 310.16.  Use a 125A breaker per 240.4(B).  "cable" is multiple "wires" stuck together, often wrapped in a sheath.  Cable is MUCH stiffer than individual wires same reason a wrapped pack of copier paper is stiff.   With cable in conduit, you are going to be VERY miserable with that pull.  You are not allowed to build the conduit around the cable, 300.18.  SER can't go underground.  If the conduit is continuous the whole way, use XHHW individual wires and upsize the conduit for easier DIY pull.
